# Scipy interp1d throws Value Error: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis

Tags: python, scipy

I am working with a 2D array of size 1465 by 12. I have another array with time values in it with the size of 1465. When I try using interp1d of scipy, I get the above error. I don't know if I am using the function correctly. The documentation of interp1d tells that I can use it for N-dimensional array as well. My implementation is as follows.

```
t = [1,2,3,4]
k=[[1,2],[2,3],[3,4],[4,5]]
interp = interp1d(t,k)
```

When I run this piece of code, I get the value error. Here please note that columns of `k` are independent of each other. To make it work, I know I can loop through each column, but I am sure the interp1d can do this already. But I am unable to figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default interpolation axis of [`interp1d`](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) is -1, which means the "y" data is along the last axis.  For your `k`, the interpolation axis should be the first axis, so use `axis=0`:

```
In [120]: t = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [121]: k = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]

In [122]: f = interp1d(t, k, axis=0)

In [123]: f(1.5)
Out[123]: array([1.5, 2.5])
```